# I'm trying to overlay a gif with a transparent background on a website as a nice effect, but it keeps displacing text

Tags: html, css

Title pretty much says it all. I'm trying to overlay a nice gif over the entirety of a pretty simple website, but it keeps on displacing other divs. Can I wrap the image such that it is in front of the text?

```
<style>
   img {
     display: block;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
   }
   .overlay {
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100vh;
   }
   body  {
     background-image: url("bgimage");
     background-color: #cccccc;
   }
</style>
<body>
   <img class="overlay" src="gif">
   <img src="logojpg" alt="alt" style="width:50%;">   
   <link href="tablogo">
</body>
```

Comment: Your post needs a code sample that show others here on SO where you're having a problem. That way they can offer useful help for your problem. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (MVCE).

Comment: Yes. Does that help? Post your code or build a minimal and verifiable example as a fiddle or similar

Comment: i added something to work with. Sorry; I'm new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off your html markup is in correct so please update it to this

```
<style>
  img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  body  {
    background-image: url("bgimage");
    background-color: #cccccc;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <img class="overlay" src="gif">
  <img src="logojpg" alt="alt" style="width:50%;">   
  <link href="tablogo">
</body>
```

and then as shown above

Give the image you want overlaying your site a unique classname or id like `class="overlay"` then in your css do something like this..

```
.overlay{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

giving your element a position of absolute takes it out of the normal flow of the webpage thus not interupting your other elements. If you want to learn more about this you can go here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Added this and it's still not working. Am I missing something?
    .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
    <div class="overlay">
    <img src="gif">
    </div>

Comment: height has to be 100vh not 100%

Comment: updated original post with current code. Still doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: No give your img the class not a div so `<img class="overlay" src="gif">`

Comment: Updated once more. Still not working and now it has .overlay{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
} 
text unformatted at the top of the page

Comment: please post a screenshot or a stackblitz of what is happening

Comment: I have also edited your html.. it was very wrong in how it was set up please confirm that is not how it is in your document because thats probably why it isnt working

Comment: https://gyazo.com/8bebefa67de9178494b7ecd0e9f1d598 This text shows up in the top left feed of the page. The gif still displaces other text and images.

Comment: Yes please post your full html document because from the looks of it, it is set up completely wrong thus why its not working

Comment: If you mean the side by side way i placed it in the comments, no, it's not like that in my document.

Comment: well something is wrong with your document so either post it or I cant help you because if it was written properly you would not have that text in the top left corner

Comment: Awesome! I will update my answer and please mark it correct